# Count the total users and display the count in the table (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

Newbie web developer here.  My target is to **get the total users under my agents and display the count in my table**. I displayed my target for now for the better visualization of my target (1 and 7). Additionally,  I provided a screenshot below for my target with explanation. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance, everyone.

[image]

**Views:**

```
//I used ajax for my table
    <script>
    
    
         $(document).ready(function(){
             
        //  Tables
            $(".allTable").on("click", function(){
                var view_id = $(this).data('id')
            
                $.ajax({
                 
                   url: "<?=site_url('network/view')?>",
        
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: { 
                    view_id: view_id  
                    
                    
                  },
                    success: function(data){
                     
                      var tbody ="";
                      var item =data.post; 
        
        
                    for(var key in item) {
                            tbody +="<tr>";
                            tbody += "<td>"+item[key].userID+"</td>";
                            tbody += "<td>"+item[key].account_type+"</td>";
                            tbody += "<td>"+item[key].firstname+" "+item[key].lastname+"</td>";
                            tbody += "<td>"+item[key].email+"</td>";
                            tbody += "<td>"+item[key].mobile+"</td>";
                            tbody += "<td>"+item[key].username+"</td>";
                            tbody += "<td>"+item[key].currentPoints+"</td>";
                            tbody +="</tr>"
                                         }
        
                  $(".tbody").html(tbody);
                  $('#editModal').modal('show');
                    }
             
                });
                })
                
        
           
         
                
         });
         
        </script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function view()
    {
        
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            $view_id = $this->input->post('view_id');
            
            if ($post = $this->networks->view($view_id)) {
                $data = array('responce' => 'success', 'post' => $post);
                
            } else {
                $data = array('responce' => 'error', 'message' => 'failed to fetch record', 'total_user_count => count($post)');
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
        } else {
            echo "No direct script access allowed";
            
        }
        
    }
```

**Model:**

```
// This is what i used for my query to get the agents under my agents. (Hierarchy Style)
    public function view($userID = 0){
            $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->from("users");
            $this->db->where( "uuid=".$userID);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $result = $query->result();
            
        }
```

Comment: And what is your problem ?

Comment: I have provided it below. I want to display the user total count on my table.

Comment: This is what my current system looks. 

https://prnt.sc/yx9irb. The screenshot i provided above is my target.